# Windows8: why use local notifications

Tags: notifications, tiles

I started off on the Win8 metro app (javascript) development recently. For notifications, it is clear how the WNS notifications will be useful for creating live tiles.

However the use case for local notifications is not clear to me. I have these two questions:

1. is it correct to assume local notifications make sense only for apps that would run in the background e.g. when other apps are running or when the system is locked?
2. if the above is not true, then kindly suggest some examples of when local notifications will be useful.

regards

CGere

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications are useful to update your tile on the start screen that persist after your app was closed/suspended. For example you might want to update the tile when your app closes with some context, perhaps an image from the last level of the game they were on or such.

When your app goes to the background it has a short period of time to suspend after which your app will no longer be running and thus unable o update the tile. You can however create a [background task](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) to run on an event/timer to do some work (such as update your tile).